# Carmine connection error during tests

Tags: clojure, compojure, luminus, compojure-api, carmine

I've a luminus project with some simple compojure-api routes.
I've added `carmine` to communicate with a redis server, using the `wcar*` macro (defined in services.clj) to make calls to it, and everything works fine.

Now I'm trying to add some tests, but seems that the redis connection doesn't works properly during them, because I'm receiving this error with `lein test`:

> ERROR Carmine connection error
>
> clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Carmine connection error {}

Since it's working in `dev` e `prod` environments, I think that is something related to a missing `env` load in the `test` environment, but I didn't find a way to solve it.

These are relevant parts of the code in use:

**test.clj**

```
(ns app.test.handler
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [ring.mock.request :refer :all]
            [app.handler :refer :all]))

(deftest test-app
  (testing "redis ping"
    (let [response ((app) (request :get "/api/redis-ping"))]
      (is (= 200 (:status response))))))
```

**services.clj**

```
(ns app.routes.services
  (:require [ring.util.http-response :refer :all]
            [compojure.api.sweet :refer :all]
            [schema.core :as s]
            [app.config :refer [env]]
            [clojure.tools.logging :as log]
            [mount.core :refer [defstate]]
            [taoensso.carmine :as car :refer (wcar)]))

(defmacro wcar* [& body] `(car/wcar
                           {:spec {:host (:redis-host env) :port (:redis-port env)}}
                           ~@body))

(defapi service-routes
     (context "/api" []
           :tags ["myapi"]

         (GET "/redis-ping" []
               :return String
               :summary "A redis client test."
               (ok (wcar* (car/ping "hello"))))))
```

**handler.clj**

```
(ns app.handler
  (:require [compojure.core :refer [routes wrap-routes]]
            [app.routes.services :refer [service-routes]]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [app.env :refer [defaults]]
            [mount.core :as mount]
            [app.middleware :as middleware]))

(mount/defstate init-app
                :start ((or (:init defaults) identity))
                :stop  ((or (:stop defaults) identity)))

(def app-routes
  (routes
    #'service-routes
    (route/not-found
      "page not found")))


(defn app [] (middleware/wrap-base #'app-routes))
```

**Profiles.clj**

```
{:profiles/dev  {:env {:redis-host "127.0.0.1" :redis-port 6381}}
:profiles/test {:env {:redis-host "127.0.0.1" :redis-port 6381}}}
```

**Config.clj**

```
(ns app.config
  (:require [cprop.core :refer [load-config]]
            [cprop.source :as source]
            [mount.core :refer [args defstate]]))

(defstate env :start (load-config
                       :merge
                       [(args)
                        (source/from-system-props)
                        (source/from-env)]))
```

**SOLUTION**

Add a text fixture with the `mount/start` command that's executed before tests.

Add to **test.clj**:

```
(defn my-test-fixture [f]
  (mount/start)
  (f))

(use-fixtures :once my-test-fixture)
```

Comment: Could you show your `app.config/env` definition?

Comment: I've just added it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `mount` to manage your application state lifecycle. I think you are not calling `(mount/start)` in your tests thus your `app.config/env` state is not initialized properly. On the other hand when you start your application `(mount/start)` is probably called and thus it's working correctly.

Comment: You're right. Trying to log `env` value at the beginning of a test results in: `;; Testing app.test.handler
;; ... #object[mount.core.DerefableState 0x6bf86b4a {:status :ready, :val #object[mount.core.NotStartedState 0x59eac843 '#'app.config/env' is not started (to start all the states call mount/start)]}]`. I'll update the question with the working code.

Comment: I think you should also call `(mount/stop)` after your tests in the fixture to have a proper test isolation (preferably in `finally` block).